# Rotate a line from one exact point to another

Tags: javascript, css, math, angle

I need to mimic an angled line being drawn between two html elements using another html element that's essentially flat (1 px height by 200 px wide) like a line. [Here's an example](http://edstage.com/test.html).

In this example, I hard-coded the angle of the line using the CSS skewY transform to make the lines angle at roughly 10px intervals. The problem is I need to do this dynamically using javascript. While already knowing the origin and destination points, I'll be using jQuery to style the line using skewY which requires a number in degrees.

How does one figure out the angle of the skew in order to have it start and end at 2 exact pixel points? I'm guessing they'll be some algebra involved.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: Have you tried using canvas? :)

Comment: Canvas isn't an option for various reasons. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

Given the known starting point, and the known ending point, and the fact that each line appears to be the longest side of a right angle triangle, I would think a bit of trigonometry could come into play.
Assumptions would be that you know the x distance between the start and the end (in your code 'one' and 'two') i.e. the horizontal - call this the adjacent, and that you should be able to establish the distance from the top (the distance from the first two, to nth two), call this the opposite then one could establish the angle (lets call it x) by SOHCAHTOA being the TOA part (or TAN angle = Opposite over adjacent) or TAN x = O/A or x = tan -1 (O/A). If I remember correctly the angle will be in radians, so will need to be converted to degrees (multiple by 180/pi)

Sample code

```
var O = //to be set
var A = //to be set

var x = Math.atan(O/A) * (180 / Math.PI)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the input! With some help from a math teacher friend, we came to the same conclusion. Here's the beginning of this concept:http://jsfiddle.net/markkanning/38tQY/.